# C++ typedefs (from MATLAB)

Tags: c++, matlab, typedef

I'm looking through some c++ code that MATLAB generated and I came across this:

```
typedef char char_T
typedef char_T byte_T
```

What exactly is this code doing and what is its purpose?

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you are asking? Do you mean to ask why byte_T is typedef'd to char_T?

Comment: What do you mean not clearly stated. I obviously said "...Why?"  haha

Comment: Yes, but what do you mean "why"? You know what a `typedef` does, and to find out why it's being used here you should ask the MATLAB authors... only they know!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I think you're asking is for the reason why MATLAB's code generator is spitting out these seemingly superfluous typedefs. The probable reason being that MATLAB wants a type that represents bytes for its code, but it's unsure of what that type is on your specific system and architecture. It then probably has a system-specific stub that maps its own types to something reasonable, and then a generic portion that uses those previously-established types.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the main theorem of programming states that any problem can be solved via adding one more layer of indirectness. The hypothetical purpose of the typedef is to use char_T everywhere, and if, say one day one decides to change the "byte type" to, say, unsigned char, one changes it to

```
typedef signed char charT
```

and there is no need to look for every place you used char and change manually.

Comment: I think maybe he's asking why char_T is mapped to byte_T... to me byte_T would be unsigned char.

Comment: @0A0D: You may well be right. But I don't think you will disagree that the question isn't very clearly stated...